# React "space" press handler not triggered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code inside a component. It is a modal that displays an image and has a `setInterval` of few seconds and displays the next image, it is actually similar to Instagram stories. The problem is that I want when this modal opens, to be able to press space and stop the `setIntreval`. I have at the top of my modal a play/pause button. You can see commented below it is inside `<section>` tag. When clicked it calls `togglePauseStoryCick` method and it works as expected. Now I want to press space and achieve same behavior. It does not work and it is not invoked because it does not display the console log. My question is, what am I doing wrong here, maybe someone can point out what is the problem and how to achieve what I want to make it work?

```
    const handleSpacePress = (e) => {
      if (e.key === 32) {
        console.log("Space clicked");
        isStoryPaused = !isStoryPaused;
      }
    };

  const togglePauseStoryCick = () => {
    console.log("Pause clicked");
    isStoryPaused = !isStoryPaused;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("event listener ");
    document.addEventListener("keydown", handleSpacePress, false);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleSpacePress, false);
    };
  }, []);

return (
    <div className="modal">
      <div className="modal-ch">
        <div className="story">
            <div
              className="main-img"
              style={{
                backgroundImage: `url(${images[currentStoryIndex]})`,
                backgroundSize: "cover",
              }}
              ref={storyModal}
            ></div>

            <div className="story-top-part">
              <div className="story-user-info-plh">
                <div className="story-profile-img"></div>
                <div className="stroy-profile-name-plh">
                  <p>username</p>
                  <section onClick={togglePauseStoryClick}>
                    {/* Play/pause button here */}  
                  </section>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="story-line-main-plh">
                  return (
                    <div className="story-line" key={index}>
                      {currentStory === story && (
                        <div
                          ref={currentStoryDisplay}
                          className="story-line-fill"
                        ></div>
                      )}
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Have u tried logging the event itself before the if? To see if the function is even being called.

Comment: Hey @user12051965, check out my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `handleSpacePress` function's condition will be

```
if (e.key === " ")
```

So updated function will be:

```
const handleSpacePress = (e) => {
    if (e.key === " ") {
        console.log("Space clicked");
        isStoryPaused = !isStoryPaused;
    }
};
```

Comment: @consager, See this demo and source in it: https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-dust-jec3v?file=/src/App.js